# Dynamical Systems Maximal Interval of Existence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Find the explicit solution and the maximal interval of existence for the initial value problem $x' = tx^3$ , $x(0) = x_0$. Recall that the maximal interval of existence depends on $x_0$, is open, and must contain $0$. Compare the maximal interval of existence to that guaranteed by the existence theorem.

Okay so for my explicit solution I got $\sqrt \frac{(x_0)^2}{1-t^2x^2}$

With this solution, the maximal interval of existence would be ($-\infty$, $\frac {1}{x_0}$)

Then we have to compute the maximal domain of existence using Picard-Lindelof Existence and Uniqueness Theorem.  In class we learned how to do it for autonomous equations (our example was $x'=x^2 , x(0)=x_0$).  We never did nonautonomous equations though.